# How to get singularity recipe from docker?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to "translate" singularity containers to a docker recipe file?

I have tried "https://github.com/singularityhub/docker2singularity" but it convert to an image file.  However, I want the recipe rather than the image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that some parameters and options are done during execution and not saved to the container, outputting an exact replicate as a recipe file does not seem to be possible.  You can always inspect the docker image and convert the Dockerfile to singularity recipe with few tweaks though.